# How to check if object property exists

Tags: templating

On Craft 3 I am iterating over matrix elements and I need to check if a certain property "videoPoster" exists. It's an asset field, so I actually want to check its length, but I'am already failing to check if it's available...

"ce" is one block of my matrix, this is what I'm doing:

```
{{ ce.videoPoster is defined ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

Works, gives me a nice "Yes"

Anything else does not work:

```
{{ ce.videoPoster is defined and ce.videoPoster ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
{{ ce.videoPoster is defined and ce.videoPoster is not null ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
{{ ce.videoPoster is defined and ce.videoPoster | length ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

Exception: Calling unknown method: craft\elements\MatrixBlock::videoPoster()

What is the correct check? I just want to know if I can call `ce.videoPost.one()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found the trick: When you access an object in array style, you can test via `is defined`

e.g.

```
{{ object['property'] is defined ? 'defined' : 'not defined' }}
```

and you will get reliable results.

Comment: I would like to stress that checking for defined using the dot notation E.G. `{{ object.property is defined ? 'defined' : 'not defined' }}` is also possible. This works multiple levels deep.

Answer (score 1):

So in general, for things like this, I think the null coalescing operator in Twig is really useful. Something like `{% set myImage = entry.someImage ?? entry.someOtherImage ?? null %}` will set `myImage` to the first thing that is defined and is not null, from left to right.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is helpful in some cases, but doesn't help here. I just want to know, if I can access the property, and if it contains at least one time (a selected asset)